# orderBy & groupBy query

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, doctrine-query

My db entries

```
id | shop_id | last_changed
1  |     1   |   7 pm
2  |     1   |   8 pm
3  |     2   |   9 pm
4  |     2   |   8 pm
5  |     3   |   5 pm
```

My query should be that I only get entries with the id:

```
2, 3, 5
```

When I do this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('list e')
         ->groupBy('e.shopname_id')
         ->orderBy('e.last_changed DESC')
         ->limit(6)
         ->fetchArray();
```

I get: `1, 4, 5`. Even if I do `e.last_changed ASC`, it doesn't work.

I want only the entries those who have `last_changed` and different `shop_id`'s. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('e.shopname_id, MAX(e.id) AS id, MAX(e.last_changed) AS last_changed')
        ->from('list e')
        ->groupBy('e.shopname_id')
        ->orderBy('MAX(e.last_changed) DESC')
        ->limit(6)
        ->fetchArray();
```